# Add new member to replicas set in mongodb with python and subprocess.call

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, subprocess, replication

i try to add new member to replicas set in mongodb. there is possibility to
do it with os.system. But how would it be with subprocess.call()?

So far i have:

```
import subprocess

task='''"rs.add('alehandro-VirtualBox:27067')"'''
port=27072
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/mongo", " --port {0}".format(port), " --eval {0}".format(task)])
```

#### OUTPUT:

> MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
>   connecting to:  --port 27072
>   Sun Jul 28 16:34:18.884 JavaScript execution failed: Error: [ --port 27072] is not a valid database name at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L40
>   exception: connect failed

Can anybody help me with it?

Comment: **task** should be `task="rs.add('alehandro-VirtualBox:27067')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongo process is being invoked with a parameter called *--port 27072* and a value of *--eval ..* because of the way you are passing your parameters to subprocess.call.

If you change the *subprocess.call* invocation to the following, then it should work :

```
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/mongo", "--port", str(port), "--eval", task])
```

Comment: It works with the right **task** value from comment to the question. Thanks jimoleary!